# How to feed OpenCV image to a trained CNN model(add a new dimension) in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, conv-neural-network

I'm getting this error `Error when checking input: expected conv2d_11_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (300, 300, 3)`
How can I pass the RGB image to a CNN? How to enumerate samples to create a 4D image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convolution function expects a batch of images, even if you have a singe image you should pass your image as:

```
#  assume img is your RGB image
#  add 4th batch dimension
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)) 

#  now you can pass it to CNN
```

Answer (score 0):

Genreally, to add a new dimension to a numpy matrix, you can use `np.newaxis` or `np.expand_dims` ( or just `reshape`)

```
import numpy as np 
nh, nw = 300, 300
x = np.random.rand(nh, nw, 3)

y = x[np.newaxis, ...]   
z = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
```

---

```
>>> x.shape
(300, 300, 3)
>>> y.shape
(1, 300, 300, 3)
>>> z.shape
(1, 300, 300, 3)
```

But if you want to feed `RGB` to a CNN model, maybe you need one more step: swap channels and convert to float32:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 

fpath = "test.png"
nh, nw = 300, 300 

img = cv2.imread(fpath)
img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(img, (nw, nh)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
ximg = np.float32(img) / 255.0 
ximg = ximg[np.newaxis, ...]
```

---

```
>>> (ximg.shape, ximg.dtype)
((1, 300, 300, 3), dtype('float32'))
```